# sqlite3_prepare_v2 return 0 row

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite

I have problem with sqlite3_prepare_v2 in xcode, I use sqlite everywhere in this class, all of my code works but not this one :

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if( sqlite3_prepare_v2( self.database, "SELECT * FROM students WHERE ( UPPER( name ) LIKE '%?%' ) OR ( LOWER( name ) LIKE '%?%' ) OR ( UPPER( firstname ) LIKE '%?%' ) OR ( LOWER( firstname ) LIKE '%?%' ) ORDER BY name, firstname", -1, &statement, nil ) != SQLITE_OK )
{
    NSLog(@"SQLITE: Failed to prepare statement! Error: '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(self.database));
    return results;
}
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [[name uppercaseString] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [[name lowercaseString] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [[firstname uppercaseString] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [[firstname lowercaseString] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Then

> while( sqlite3_step( statement ) == SQLITE_ROW ) {
>       ...
>       [results addObject:p]; }

And finally

> sqlite3_finalize( statement );

This code works when I change sql select by

> SELECT * FROM students

My database table students return 12 rows when I test it in navicat.

Thank's for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `sqlite3_bind_text` calls return `SQLITE_RANGE` because this statement does not have any parameters.

A question sign inside a string like `'%?%'` is just a normal character.
For a parameter, the question sign must be outside any string.

To get the percent signs into that string, you have to concatenate them all:

```sql
... WHERE name LIKE '%' || ? || '%' ...
```

(Please note that LIKE is case insensitive; UPPER or LOWER will not change anything.)